# ¿Se puede generar múltiples informes en Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

Necesito generar generar más de 100 informes con los mismos textos y formatos, pero con diferentes imágenes en la misma posición para cada informe mediante Rmarkdown. 
Las imágenes fueron creadas mediante R y guardas en cada carpeta para ser destinados a los informes respectivos que espero generar.
De antemano, muchas gracias.

Un ejemplo cercano, sería asi:

````
---
title: "BEN"
author: ""
date: ""
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE)
```


# REPORTE DE RESULTADOS

Empresa:
```{r echo=FALSE}
NombreEmpresa<-p.1.1 
```


## 1. TIPOS DE INNOVACIÓN 
¿Qué tipo de innovación se ha desarrollado?
![](1.jpeg){width=50%}

 ![Porcentaje que realizan el tipo de innovación señalada.](1.1.jpeg){width=40%}
````

Cada carpeta tiene el nombre de la empresa y dentro de ella, tiene el nombre de las imágenes.

Comment: Bienvenido Matias Parravicini a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Por que no armas un ejemplo básico en código del Rmd que quieres replicar con distintas imágenes? Eso sin duda ayudará  a que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí, se puede.

Necesitas crear una plantilla .Rmd en la que se evalúen variables que definen el contenido que cambia.

Luego crear un script en el que usas `rmarkdown::render()` para generar el output, en lugar de crearlo con el ícono de `Knit`. En ese mismo script defines el valor de las variables que están en el .Rmd (en tu caso podría ser el path y nombre de archivo de las imágenes que quieres enlazar al documento) y estas variables estarán disponibles en el entorno de `render()` y las podrá usar el .Rmd. Va un ejemplo mínimo que **no** soluciona tu problema, pero no sabría como hacerlo pq no has incluido un ejemplo mínimo y reproducible.

## La plantilla de rmarkdown

Esto se guardaría como `plantilla.Rmd` o el nombre que quieras, es un archivo común y corriente .Rmd

````
---
title: "Prueba de multireportes"
author: "Martín Paladino"
date: "12/4/2020"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Voy a graficar la distribución de cada variable del data set `mtcars`


```{r cars}
plot(variable_elegida)   #Este objeto está definido en script.R y disponible aquí
```
````

Uso solo una variable (`variable_elegida`), pero podrías pasar una lista o un índice de un bucle `for()`

## El script

Aquí hay dos pasos:

- Crear la lista nombrada de elementos sobre la que voy a iterar el render. En este caso es muy simple (las columnas de un df), pero podría ser cualquier lista arbitraria, incluyendo una lista de listas si necesitas pasar muchas variables a `render()`.

  - Es importante que sea nombrada para tener una referencia con la que nombrar los archivos después.
- Iterar con `purrr::imap()` la función `render()` en cada elemento de la lista y obtener tantos outputs como elementos tiene la lista.

  - Uso `imap()` porque me permite pasar a los nombres como segundo argumento.
  - Como `render()` se evalúa en el entorno de `imap()` cada elemento de la lista cambia en cada iteración. `R` a veces es sorprendentemente elegante.

Este es el código:

```
library(purrr)

data("mtcars")  #Para no llamar a la librería completa

imap(mtcars, function(variable_elegida, nombre) {
  rmarkdown::render(
    #Indico en qué archivo está la plantilla, atención al path
    input = "plantilla.Rmd",
    #Podría ser html o docx
    output_format = "pdf_document",
    output_file = paste("variable_",    #Base del nombre de archivo
                        nombre,         #Nombre en la lista del elementos para identificar el archivo
                        ".pdf",         #IMPORTANTE: cambiar a .html o .docx si usamos otro output, sino pandoc se confunde
                        sep = ''),
    output_dir = "pdf"                  #Para que no se llene la raíz de archivos
  )                
})
```

## Posibles problemas:

Prestar atención al entorno en el que se cargan las librerías que podrías estar usando. En mi caso uso solo `base::`, pero podrás tener que importar las librerías en el `.Rmd`.

`render()` se evalúa en la carpeta en la que esté el script a menos que indiquemos explícitamente otra cosa.

La parte más difícil es armar bien la lista sobre la que se itera, sobre todo si está anidada. En tu caso podrías usar `list.files()` para crear una lista con los nombres de archivo de las imágenes que vas a usar y pasar el path a `render()`. De nuevo, atención al path.